# High resolution image viewer/tiler that returns row, col of clicked pixel

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, coordinates, tiff

I am trying to setup an image viewer/server/tiler that will take a large (>~10gb) .tif file and tile it in an html5/js viewer.

Essentially, the application will:

- Tile the image on the server - on-the-fly would be great since users will be uploading their own images
- Display the tif image (full or tiled)

  - Zoom enabled
  - Pan enabled
  - Preferably javascript / html5
- On click event, draw a marker

  - Return x,y (row,col) for that marker

So far I've looked at [IIP Imager Server](http://iipimage.sourceforge.net/documentation/server/). But it doesn't seem to able to return an x,y (row, col) or draw a marker on a click event. Plus, the documentation appears poorly written and setting it up is incredibly difficult. So I want to make sure that it's even possible to do these actions with IIP Image Viewer, before going through hours of work setting up the server.

I've also looked at [MapTiler](https://code.google.com/p/maptiler/). This works great on tiling a large image to place in the google maps api. The *problems* with this is that 1) you now have to pay for most of it unless you use the older version, and 2) you have to tile the images manually and place them on the server before you can use them. (unless their is a command line method that I don't know about??)

Users will be uploading their images individually, then view them in the viewer and be able to click the pixel and return the x,y.

Any tips or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Users will be uploading >10GB files?

Comment: Actually, they'll be uploading (via ftp) ~2gb files where a mosaic will be created using MatLab that can result in 10gb or larger tif files. The upload isn't important as much as viewing/returning values for the final tif image.

Comment: Not really helping here, just like to point out that [the maximum file size for TIFF is ~4GB](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/faq.html#q8). You could of course use BigTIFF, but I think support is less common.